# Python indentation not interpreted.

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I have what seems to be a simple issue and I cannot seem to remedy it.

To illustrate the error, If I run:

```
a = 'h'
b = 'h'

if b == a:
    print('a is b')
else:
    print('a is not b')
```

I get :

```
>>> a = 'h'
>>>
>>> b = 'h'
>>>
>>> if b == a:
...
  File "<stdin>", line 2

    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Python does not seem to be interpreting the indent.

As well, if I run the following as a block (no indents):

```
line_one = 'one'
line_two = 'two'
line_three = 'three'
print(line_one)
print(line_two)
print(line_three)
```

The output I get is:

```
>>> line_one = 'one'
>>>
>>> line_two = 'two'
>>>
>>> line_three = 'three'
>>>
>>> print(line_one)
one
>>>
>>> print(line_two)
two
>>>
>>> print(line_three)
three
```

The interpreter seems to be adding a new line or an escape at the end of each line when run as a block. I'm suspecting this is causing the indent error.

If it matters I'm running Python 3.7.0 on VS Code x64 1.28.1

Thanks you for your time.

Comment: How are you running this?

Comment: Selecting the code and hitting `ctrl+enter`

Comment: Do you mean Shift+Enter? Ctrl+Enter is "Insert Line Below", according to [the docs I found](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_basic-editing).

Comment: If you have any weird custom macros or keybindings for Ctrl+Enter, it's likely that something's wrong with them.

Comment: Take a look at this extension package. It does the automatic indentation for you. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python

Comment: I set the keyboard shortcut of 'Run Selection/Line' to be Ctrl+Enter, and removed the other shortcuts with Ctrl+Enter and it still behaves the same.

Comment: Update on this, deleted all extensions and settings, and reinstalled vs code. Same issue using the default key shortcut of Shift+Enter. Moved back to try on two previous versions, same issue.

Comment: The immediate issue appears to be that your code is getting extra newlines inserted between each real code line. That's why you see extra `>>>`s in between the top level statements. Those empty lines are the cause of your larger issue, as they are breaking the indented blocks in your interactive session. I don't know enough obout VS Code to solve that issue for you. Perhaps there's a file encoding issue somewhere, and you are getting extra characters being interpreted by Python as newlines (e.g. `\r\n` being interpreted as two separate newlines, rather than one)?